# Loop into a array depending the key

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP, how can I loop only in a part of the multidimensional array ?

For example how to loop into `red` fruits ?

```
$fruits = array(
    'red' => array('apple', 'cherry'),
    'yellow' => array('lemon'),
    'orange' => array('orange')
);
```

Thanks.

Comment: You know how to access an array element, right?  You know how to `foreach`, right?  Combine the two.

Comment: Please add the code you came up with already, as well as your desired output / behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a normal foreach loop over the inner array. You just need to specify that key rather than iterating the entire `$fruits` array. Like this:

```
foreach ($fruits['red'] as $red_fruit) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop the item you want with `foreach`:

```
foreach($fruits['red'] as $fruit) {
   // do something
}
```